# Android Studio 3.5 - Formatting (ctrl+Alt+L) the code in XML file is rearranging the Views in the LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-xml, android-studio-3.5

Recently I have updated to Android Studio 3.5. I have three views: an EditText, a TextView and a Button inside a vertical LinearLayout(ViewGroup) named sample.xml file.
When I format the stuff by pressing ctrl+alt+L, all the views get rearranged automatically. In my case the Button view which is in the bottom has reached to top after formatting, also EditText and TextView which is in top first and second are rearranged in second and third position respectively in vertical LinearLayout.

> Android Studio : 3.5
>
> Android Gradle Plugin: 3.5.0
>
> Gradle: 5.4.1
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03x64
>
> OS: Windows 8.1(amd64) v6.3

Comment: i was also facing the same issue. I deleted the configuration and then all were good

Comment: this happpens when you upgrade the android studio.Try uninstalling the 3.5 and make a fresh install.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Please try below settings that worked for me

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML-> Set From -> Predefined Style > Android.
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working!!!

Comment: I did this and worked.

Comment: I wonder how it got funky in the first place...

Comment: Thanks. You saved lives :p